# Kubernetes cluster in GCloud with koops: public key denied

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kops

I am deploying a 2-node Kubernetes cluster on GCloud using kops with the following commands:

```
kops create cluster part1.k8s.local --zones europe-west3-a --node-count 2 --node-image ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-2004-focal-v20210129 --node-size "e2-standard-2" --ssh-public-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --state ${KOPS_STATE_STORE}/ --project=${PROJECT}
```

```
kops update cluster --name part1.k8s.local --yes --admin
```

I then wait for the cluster to be ready and get the external IP of one of the nodes using:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

However when I try to login to the node I get:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa admin@<PUBLIC_IP>
admin@<PUBLIC_IP>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Checking the permissions the nodes should be able to accept SSH connections and I can connect to the VMs using the GCloud UI.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Root cause was that you have used wrong image in command? I see that the same question was asked on github (by you, based on github name) but it's still in open status. Does this change solved this issue?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of "wrong image". Based on the github issue, they don't update the other images so often (rather than the default) and also GCloud is in beta, so these issues are expected.

Comment: Could you share output of `ls ~/.ssh`? What if you would try to ssh usign `gcloud compute ssh <instance-1> --zone <VM zone>`? Also what output you will get if you will execute `ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine USERNAME@EXTERNAL_IP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/10770

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer and provide solution not as link to another forum? It will be more visible for community if someone else will encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've encounter the issue when I tested some scenarios with `SSH keys` (add, remove, overwrite, etc).

When you are logging to `GKE` console, your `ssh keys` are stored in `~/.ssh`. If folder it's empty, those keys will be created ocne you will connect to VM (google_compute_engine and google_compute_engine.pub).

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
google_compute_engine  google_compute_engine.pub  google_compute_known_hosts  known_hosts
```

Information about `SSH Key` is also stored in your project. You can find it in **Navigation Menu** > **Compute Engine** > **Metadata**. Next select **SSH Keys tab** to view instance `SSH keys`.

Additional information about `SSH Keys` can be found in [Managing SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) guide.

If you will encounter this kind of issue, you can remove `SSH key` from UI, remove `google_compute_engine` and `google_compute_engine.pub`. While you want to `SSH` to machine, GKE will ask you to create new SSH key and issue with `Permission denied (publickey)` should be fixed.

Commands which should be used to `ssh` to `GCE` vm is [gcloud ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)

```
gcloud compute ssh <instance-name> --zone <zone>
```

Why?

> gcloud compute ssh is a thin wrapper around the ssh(1) command that takes care of authentication and the translation of the instance name into an IP address.

In addition, if you will encounter other `SSH` issues on `GKE` you can check [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) guide.